# Can I affect SQL Generated by Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm, query-performance

I have table contents mapped to java class Content, with some subclassess(Recommendation, MarketAnnouncement.) mapped using table-per-subclass strategy to tables recommendations, market_announcements and so on.

When I retrieve Content instances using Criteria, Hibernate generates a SQL query which looks like:

```
  SELECT this_.ID AS ID4_1_,this_.version AS version4_1_
    [...]
    CASE
    WHEN this_3_.content_id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
    WHEN this_9_.CONTENT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 9
    [...]
    END AS clazz_1_,
    FROM content.contents this_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN content.recommendations this_3_ ON this_.ID=this_3_.content_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN content.market_announcements this_9_ ON this_.ID=this_9_.CONTENT_ID
    [...]
    INNER JOIN content.content_categories cat1_ ON this_.CONTENT_CATEGORY_ID=cat1_.ID
    WHERE cat1_.name IN ('daily-report')
    AND this_.date_published<=now()
    AND (this_.PUBLICATION_STATUS IS NULL
    OR this_.PUBLICATION_STATUS<>'DRAFT')
    [...]
```

A join with content.content_categories in most cases filters out nearly all rows, so the query could be very light.

However postgresql performs this join after applying conditions on date_published, publication_status and so on.

These conditions are very costly because they require a sequence scan on content.contents (because most of the rows meet conditions).

I modified this query by hand and I moved up that INNER JOIN:

```
FROM content.contents this_
INNER JOIN content.content_categories cat1_ ON this_.CONTENT_CATEGORY_ID=cat1_.ID AND cat1_.name IN ('daily-report')
LEFT OUTER JOIN content.recommendations this_3_ ON this_.ID=this_3_.content_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN content.market_announcements this_9_ ON this_.ID=this_9_.CONTENT_ID
[...]
WHERE this_.date_published<=now()
[...]
```

Now the query plan looks much more better because postgresql performs join with content.content_categories first. This removes most of the rows so applying conditions is very cheap.

My question is: is it possible to affect such Hibernate-generated query and force specific JOIN to be placed on the desired position?

Comment: I have not read your question. may be property you're looking for is:
hibernate.query.substitutions

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the criterion `cat1_.name IN ('daily-report')` as one of the first. Hibernate doesn't reorder criteria as far as I know.

If that doesn't work, you can use HQL or tell Hibernate to fetch with a custom SQL.

If you don't want to do your own queries, try to split the query into two and then join them in on the Java side (like get the small set of rows from the inner query and then use the PKs in an `in()` criterion on the second query).